# Ruby: How to run "dpkg-reconfigure" inside code?

Tags: ruby

In my Ruby code, I am trying to call "dpkg-reconfigure" but it won't show.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

`dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`
```

The program just hangs up without GUI interface.

Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `system`, instead of capturing the output using backticks.

```
system "dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates"
```